# Disable some of the RestAPI admin endpoints of Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am on Keycloak 21.0.2.

How can I disable some of the RestAPIs Keycloak provided. For example I want to have the token & user endpoints:

```
http://KEYCLOAK_URL/realms/{REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

and

```
http://KEYCLOAK_URL/realms/{REALM}/users/*
```

But not having groups endpoints:

```
http://KEYCLOAK_URL/realms/{REALM}/groups/*
```